# Dynamic button link to a page with different content

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to click a lesson(button) to go to a page(showcontent.php). As my lesson number is created by using the sql statement:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT lesson FROM table"
```

This is my php file

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password","database");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT lesson FROM table");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
//depending on the lesson number in the database
//If lesson column only have lesson 2 and 5; it will show 2 buttons, lesson 2 and lesson 5
$lesson = $row['lesson'];
echo "<a href=>LESSON ". $row['lesson'] ."</a>\n";
echo "<br>";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

So what I want is to click the lesson button to link a page(showcontent.php) but the content which I retrieve from the database will be different. Means when I click lesson 2 it will go to (showcontent.php) and when I click lesson 5 it will go to (showcontent.php) but the contents will be different. And the content I have to retrieve from the database.

What I have done is only (showcontent.php), it only display for lesson 1.
This is the php file.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","database");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$x = 7;

$sql="select * from sen where id = ".$x." limit 10";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
$output = $row[1];
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

So what I need is make the program knows that when I click lesson 1(button) it will go to (showcontent.php) and get the content for lesson 1 from that database. However, when I click lesson 5(button) it will go to (showcontent.php) and get the content for lesson 5 from that database. How can I make that work? Any examples?

Comment: Best way to do this is ajax.

Comment: When you click on a button you need to send information to the server that will modify your query in showcontent.php by changing an id or some other value that can be gotten from the database. Then your query can be something like `"SELECT lesson FROM table WHERE id = 'foo'"`

Comment: If I want to create a variable for the lesson number so that it will detect when I click lesson 1 it will display the content from the database WHERE lesson 1 is clicked. Is there a better alternative other than creating many if else statement. For example, create a var x as the lesson number. Then when button is click it will document.get(""); Where lesson = $x. How can I do that?